# Cannot bind radio button input in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I gone through the documentation and I tried the following code. I am able to get the data for `enquiryDesc` but getting null values for rating. I tried several steps and getting null values.

My html form is

```
<form id="enquiryBox" method="POST" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="handelSubmit($event);">
  <div class="modal-body brbottom-20">
    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <fieldset class="rating">
            <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="5" ><label v-bind:value="5" class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome"></label>
               <input v-model="rating" type="radio" id="rating" name="rating" value="4" ><label v-bind:value="4" class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good"></label>
               </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group required">
          <label>Enquiry</label>
          <textarea placeholder="Write your enquiry here" rows="7" id="enquiryDesc" name="enquiryDesc" class="form-control required" title="Desc" v-model="enquiryDesc" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <button id="btn-submit-enquiry" class="btn whiteButton" type="submit">Post Enquiry</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My vue js script is as

```
enquiryBox = new Vue({
   el: "#enquiryBox",
   data: {
     rating: '',
     enquiryDesc: '',
   },
   methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
       var vm = this;
       data = {};
       data['rating'] = this.rating;
       data['enquiryDesc'] = this.enquiryDesc;
       console.log(data);

       $.ajax({
         url: 'https://api/post/add_review/',
         data: data,
         type: "POST",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(e) {
           if (e.status) {
             alert("Success")

           } else {
             vm.response = e;

             alert(" Failed")
           }
         }
       });
       return false;
     }
   },
 });
```

My response for `console.log(data)`

> {rating: "", enquiryDesc: "cg"}

I have used `v-model` and `v-bind:value` and now to I am not the values. I am really stuck on these. Is something not initialized? Please help me to have a solution.I have gone through several tutorials and everything says to do in the same way.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set a default value for rating? Because initially there is no value (you set it to '' in data). You have to select a rating for it to be populated.

Comment: As already stated, be sure that you're actually selecting a radio button. If you are but are still running into problems, that will give us a better look into the underlying issues. If you're not selecting one, however, then this is expected behavior. Nothing looks immediately wrong, but I do recommend getting rid of the `onSubmit="return false;"` and updating your `v-on:submit` to `v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit()"` in your form tag. This will prevent default submit behavior using vue's own built-in functionality.

Comment: @Bert based on the radio button value needs to be changed. If I set rating: 5, always I am getting the value as 5. It is not changing

Comment: @B.Fleming Sir, I made the changes you have said.. but still no luck. I am not able to get the radio button value which I am selecting.

Comment: @Wanderer I'm honestly not sure why you're running into problems. When I use your code in this JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/m5gez1ry/), I'm able to get the correct values from the radio inputs. What platform are you testing on, and which browser are you using?

Comment: When I use <select> I am able to change values <select class="dropdown" v-model="rating"> <option v-bind:value="0">Your rating</option> <option v-bind:value="1">1.Poor</option> </select> WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH <RADIO BUTTON>

Comment: Sir.. this script icheck.min.js is causing me the problem. If I remove this script.. all the style does not work.. but radio buttons will work